# how to achieve the generic input parameter property name in foreach looping

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics, c#-4.0

how to loop through a generic parameter method?

I have a collection with generic method.

```
public void DoSomething<T>(List<T> input)
{
    // I want to foreach
    foreach (var v in input)
    {
        byte[] data = v.Data;
        string name = v.Name;
    }
}
```

My problem is: I dont get Data and Name in V. its generic. How to achieve it

Comment: Why are you taking a `List<T>`, and not a `List<Foo>` where `Foo` is your class which has the properties `Data` and `Name`? Is it because you have multiple types which all have the properties `Data` and `Name`?

Comment: `public void DoSomething<T>(List<T> input) where T: IFoo` i.e.`T` implements `IFoo`  which provides `Data` and `name` properties

Comment: You could drop generics and do something like `DoSomething(IEnumerable<IFoo> input)` since `IEnumerable` is co-variant you can pass anything that implements the interface with items that implement `IFoo`.

Comment: @juharr: Sorry I am afraid I dont understand these lol I am a newbie

Comment: If you take a look at concepts like the Onion Architecture, it is not a bad practice to make business objects aka domain entities that are shared by the entire architecture.   If you keep the business objects simple (just buckets of data, my mentor used to say), and implement the functions in the correct part of the architecture (i.e. not in the business object itself) the concept is quite powerful and flexible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have all of your generic inputs implement a Interface, which exposes the properties you need. You then need to put a constraint on your generic `T` in order to make use of those properties:

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<RandomData>();

    DoSomething(list);
}

public void DoSomething<T>(List<T> input) where T : IData
{
    foreach(var v in input)
    {
        byte[] data = v.Data;
        string name = v.Name;
    }
}

public interface IData
{
    byte[] Data { get; set; }

    string Name { get; set; }
}

class RandomData : IData
{
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It looks good, but defeats my whole purpose of creating generics. My requirement is very very simple, not a brainy thing. I just make a class reusable library (It WILL NOT have any of my business objections, in this case RandomData). I don't want to refer Business Objects project DLL in Reusable component and vice versa. So I dont even have to make it generic if I have to do so

Comment: @Learner you can't use your business objects without somehow referencing them. How should the compiler know what you're trying to do.

Comment: I just gave a thought. Does it mean, you want me to create this interface of properties and the class that implement in the same reusable class library project? Its same as my business object you mean?

Comment: A copy of my Business Object in reusable class you mean, so that it just accepts when I call from outside ...

Comment: @Learner no that's not what i mean, what you're thinking of won't work. The only thing you'd have to declare in the "reuseable" class is the Interface and your business object needs to implement the interface from the "reuseable" class.

Comment: Ok, that means, you want me to create this interface in reusable class project and you want me to refer the reusable component DLL onto the business object and implement that class using this interface? I already have the class there...just matter of creating this interface in reusuable component project and refer this dll in BO? is that what you meant?

Comment: @Learner exactly.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can understand now. Hope my lead is ok with my design when he reviews :P lol...Thank you :) :)

Comment: Actually, its my first generics method, and generics understanding in 10 years lol. Now I practically to some extent understand. :) Until now, just for interviews I understood theoretically, but couldn't type with my hand with understanding. I am a business analyst by mindset, but have no option but to code for bread. So thanks to you as I really learnt something I feel today and I am proud to seee something fancy I coded lol...

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is to create a general method that iterates over some specific type to do something special, and in this case it will be because of a shared common behavior, so there is no added value in creating a generic method that iterates over specific members to do something if there is no common thing between them so in your case you can put a condition on the generic type to implement an interface:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(List<T> input) where T : ICommonLogic
{
    foreach(var v in input)
    {
        byte[] data = v.Data;
        string name = v.Name;
    }
}
```

Or even cleaner by adding an extension:

```
public static class CommonLogicExtensions
{
   public static DoSomething(this IEnumerable<ICommonLogic> input)
   {
        foreach(var v in input)
        {
            byte[] data = v.Data;
            string name = v.Name;
        }
   }
}
```

The uses of generics are somewhat different, for example creating a data structure that takes different type of objects like the `List`, but when it comes to specific or special behaviors a common interface should be used instead.

Comment: It looks fancy, I am layman lol I dont understand it :( But yours looks hi-fi....Sorry I am junior...